# not able to login to facebook using oauth

Tags: android, facebook, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am using Xamarin oauth for logging into facebook
I downloaded the sample application from [this url](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth)

And i created a facebook app and got an application id

I tried to replace that in the code block for the application id

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
                clientId: "113265011xxxx6",
                scope: "",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

            auth.AllowCancel = allowCancel;
```

When i tried to login to facebook i got the below error screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to this URL https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR-APP-ID
and enable the "`Client OAuth login` under **Client OAuth settings**".

[image]

Also give a valid url for `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

Comment: Please edit your answer and improve formating. thanks